# Which was the comic where Steve Rogers was able to hold Thor's hammer?

Tags: marvel, comics, captain-america, episode-identification, mjolnir

Which was the comic book where Captain America became worthy to hold Mjolnir ?

Answer (score 4):

He has done so on at least two occasions:
[image: captainamerica]

This happens in:

- The Mighty Thor #390 (1988)

> During a period where Steve had abandoned the mantle of Captain
>   America and gone independent as "The Captain." Cap paid a visit to his
>   buddy Thor at Avengers Mansion, only for the team to be attacked by
>   Grog and the Demons of Death (great band name). When Thor was subdued
>   by the combined might of these villains, Cap was able to lift Mjolnir
>   long enough to send it back to its rightful owner.

- Fear Itself #7 (2011)

> Cap had the chance to wield Mjolnir for a slightly longer stretch in
>   the event Fear Itself. With his trusty shield having been shattered by
>   the Serpent, Cap had nothing but some automatic weapons to battle the
>   Serpent's minions. Luckily for him, Thor lost his grip on Mjolnir
>   during his battle with his uncle. Mjolnir crashed to Earth, and Cap
>   hoisted it high and led the charge.

[Some more info who was able to wield Thor's hammer](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/09/30/12-other-characters-who-have-lifted-thors-hammer-mjolnir)